# neodymium magnet - how it affects a circuit

Tags: connector, magnetics

I am trying to develop a connector which can join both sides by a magnet. I got the idea of using a neodymium magnet , but I was thinking that if this could in one way or another affect circuit operation. This is an example of what I'm trying to do

[image]

Comment: Just have a look at all the other cabels that use similar attachment methods...

Comment: I've been watching , and found the connector with the macbook, but that is the connector that plugs into the laptop , I wonder if being close to an integrated circuit or a specific , need to be isolated or not cause any serious damage

Comment: What stops the polarity becoming reversed?

Comment: The question is not if it affects a lot, found a similar question on a page where someone answered , if the magnet is not very big in no way affects or does not do with much intensity .

Comment: Why is this a good idea?

Comment: I do not understand the question?

Answer (score 2):

If a magnet passes by a conductor a current is induced in the conductor, this is the principal operation of generators. If that magnet stands still then the conductor is entirely unaffected.

If a current is passing through a conductor a magnetic field forms around the conductor. That magnetic field can tug on components. This effect can be demonstrated with a compass. Unless you plan to conduct hundreds or thousands of amps of current then you are quite safe in that respect. If the tug action was important then traces would fly off circuit boards all the time.

The more important thing you need to keep in mind is contact resistance. The magnets would have to align perfectly to ensure low contact resistance. In regular male female type connectors the female end is flexible ensuring maximum contact area to reduce contact resistance.

Some Apple laptops have a similar connector, the difference being that the magnets just align and hold. The contacts in this case are not magnetic, one side is fixed and the other side is springy to allows maximum contact.

Comment: Thank you for all that clarification , but I see that maybe I forgot to say in the graph, where positive and negative outputs will be copper or any conductive material are common , and would not be through magnets .

Magnet function in case I propose is only to hold the plug but not included as conductor.

Comment: not entirely unaffected. with a constant magnetic field and an electric current there is hall effect, but it is very small even in the presence of srtong magnetic fields.